# GMP compile error: No rule to make target `mpn/add_n.lo', needed by `libgmp.la'

Tags: android, android-ndk, vlc, gmp

I am compiling the VLC for Android on Ubuntu 12.04, basing on this [instruction](http://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile)

Always get this error when compiling the libgmp

```
ibstdc++/4.7/include -I/home/jerry/workspaces/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.7/libs/armeabi-v7a/include -DNDEBUG  -I/home/jerry/workspaces/vlc/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi/include -g -c -o mpn/add.lo mpn/add.c
/bin/bash ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/jerry/workspaces/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm -std=gnu99 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP  -g -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mcpu=cortex-a8 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=softfp -O2 -I/home/jerry/workspaces/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.7/include -I/home/jerry/workspaces/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.7/libs/armeabi-v7a/include -DNDEBUG  -I/home/jerry/workspaces/vlc/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi/include  -g -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mcpu=cortex-a8 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=softfp -O2 -I/home/jerry/workspaces/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.7/include -I/home/jerry/workspaces/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.7/libs/armeabi-v7a/include -DNDEBUG  -I/home/jerry/workspaces/vlc/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi/include -g -c -o mpn/add_1.lo mpn/add_1.c
make[3]: *** No rule to make target `mpn/add_n.lo', needed by `libgmp.la'.  Stop.
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/jerry/workspaces/vlc/vlc/contrib/android/gmp'
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/jerry/workspaces/vlc/vlc/contrib/android/gmp'
make[1]: *** [install] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/jerry/workspaces/vlc/vlc/contrib/android/gmp'
make: *** [.gmp] Error 2
```

Does anyone know to correct this problem?

Comment: 1) Your link doesn't mention GMP. 2) The rules are the same on SO as everywhere, if you want help, show what you did (configure options, environment, etc), not just the last few lines of compiler output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error and GMP is still at version 4.2.1 but this was not the problem for me. A lot of other packages also failed. The problem was due to two different (and somehow incompatible) versions of `libtool`. Version 2.2.10 is provided by vlc itself in `vlc/extras/tools`, the other came from the distribution (Mint) at version 2.4.2. `make clean` in this tools-folder solved it for me, if it doesn't for you, you could try to set `LIBTOOL_VERSION=2.4.2` or whatever version your distro provides in `configure.mak`.
The root cause was that at when `config.status` concatenates the config with ltmain.sh, some major parts of ltmain.sh are lost, so no compilation was done at all, hence the missing dependency.

After that everything compiled fine (didn't try to install though).

```
-rw-r--r--  1 user user 8437456 Jun  5 21:00 VLC-debug.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug of the GMP, I fixed it by upgrading the GMP to v5.0+

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because gmp/Makefile does not include gmp/mpn/Makeasm.am.

I don't know why but just copying gmp/mpn/Makeasm.am to the end of gmp/Makefile.am worked for me.

Upgrading gmp to version 5.1.2 did not help me.

Answer (score 0):

Compiled fine with 5.1.1 https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gmp/gmp-5.1.1.tar.lz

I got similer error with gmp-6.0.0 and gmp-6.2.1 too, they were slightly different though.